# Problem: Resetting section counter in appendix with apa6 class

Tags: appendices, apa6

I aim to have two separate appendices that start with "Appendix A" at the end of my document (the first is an *appendix*, the second a *supplementary material*). The solution is usually to use  `\setcounter{section}{0}` in between appendices.

What I want is

***Appendix A: First One***

...

***Supplement A: Second one***

But what I get is

***Appendix A: First One***

...

***Supplement B: Second one***

Here is a minimal code example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \title{\textbf{The title of the article}}
  \shorttitle{Short title}
  \author{Me}
  \twoaffiliations{Department of X, Y}
  \journal{Journalname}

  \section{Introduction}
  Text Text Text

  \appendix
  \section{First One}
   Some text for first appendix

  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Supplement}
  \section{Second One}
   Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me out?

I tried using `\begin{appendices} ... \end{appendices}` of the appendix package, but could not make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean `\begin{appendices}`... most likely... But I find it very confusing to have two (!!!) appendices 'numbered' with 'A'

Comment: What's the use of having two appendices with the same reference?

Comment: I clarified (first = appendix, second = supplementary material), I know usually its NOT a good idea, see updated question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a command `\supplement` analogues to `\appendix` and use another counter?

Comment: yepp would be cleaner

Comment: @Schweinebacke: It would be cleaner, but at least in this aspect `apa6` does not seem well-defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apa6.cls` redefines `\section` within `\appendix` and defines a counter `appendix`. The new `\section` macro does not use `\refstepcounter{section}` any longer, so `\setcounter{section}{0}` does effectively nothing.

In addition, there is a `\oneappendixfalse` switch.

Of course, references are confusing for such a scheme and `hyperref` (if used) will also be confused!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\oneappendixfalse
\begin{document}

  \title{\textbf{The title of the article}}
  \shorttitle{Short title}
  \author{Me}
  \twoaffiliations{Department of X, Y}
  \journal{Journalname}

  \section{Introduction}
  Text Text Text

  \appendix
  \section{First One}
   Some text for first appendix

  \setcounter{appendix}{0}
  \section{Second One}
   Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: Christian, thanks so much, especially (!) for the explanation of the internal workings of apa6 - LOVE your answer, I will accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: @JBJ: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

If there are just one appendix and one supplement, I find no reason for numbering them: they should just be “Appendix” and “Supplement”.

The `apa6` class checks how many `\section` commands are issued after `\appendix`, so as to decide whether numbering them: it doesn't add a number if only one section is present.

How does this work? If the `appendix` counter is greater than 1 at the end of the document, `\global\oneappendixfalse` is written to the `aux` file.

So it's easy to get the “right” output by changing

```
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

into

```
\setcounter{appendix}{0}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{The title of the article}}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Me}
\twoaffiliations{Department of X, Y}
\journal{Journalname}

\section{Introduction}
Text Text Text

\appendix
\section{First One}
Some text for first appendix

\setcounter{appendix}{0}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplement}

\section{Second One}
Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have two or more supplements and one appendix, do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{The title of the article}}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Me}
\twoaffiliations{Department of X, Y}
\journal{Journalname}

\section{Introduction}
Text Text Text

\appendix
\oneappendixtrue
\section{First One}
Some text for first appendix

\oneappendixfalse
\setcounter{appendix}{0}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplement}

\section{Second One}
Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\section{Third one}
Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\end{document}
```

For two or more appendices and one supplement do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{The title of the article}}
\shorttitle{Short title}
\author{Me}
\twoaffiliations{Department of X, Y}
\journal{Journalname}

\section{Introduction}
Text Text Text

\appendix
\oneappendixfalse
\section{First One}
Some text for first appendix

\section{Second One}
Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\oneappendixtrue
\setcounter{appendix}{0}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplement}

\section{Third one}
Some text for my second freshly started appendix

\end{document}
```

If you have several appendices and several supplements, leave out the `\oneappendixtrue` and `\oneappendixfalse` declarations.